# How do I add days to a Chrono UTC?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I am trying to find the preferred way to add days to a Chrono `UTC`. I want to add 137 days to the current time:

```
let dt = UTC::now();
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just use [`Duration`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.Duration.html) and appropriate [operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html):

```rust
use chrono::{Duration, Utc};

fn main() {
    let dt = Utc::now() + Duration::days(137);

    println!("today date + 137 days {}", dt);
}
```

[Test on playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6e36d1660566d1b60487b681c8ba199).

Comment: Thank you, i missed the arithmetic part.  Great community, great crates. The documentation format tho feels like I am reading MSDN.  Thanks for the correct easy answer, a lot better than what i was doing after reading through those docs for the 11th time :-)

Comment: Wow! This is much better than momentJS

Comment: It's worth noting that the "+ Duration" function is implemented for DateTime<_>, but the reverse is NOT true, so while 

```Utc::now() + Duration::days(137)``` works
the reverse does not:
```Duration::days(137) + Utc::now()```

Answer (score 46):

I just wanted to improve on @Stargateur answer. There is no need to use `time` crate, since `chrono` crate has `Duration` struct in it:

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::{Duration, Utc};

fn main() {
    let dt = Utc::now() + Duration::days(137);

    println!("{}", dt);
}
```

[Another test on playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=c02aa7cc77d77ba018c169cdd16394ab&version=stable)

Comment: Note that currently `Duration` is just a wrapper to `time::Duration`, there could be breaking change by using `Duration` directly

Comment: @Stargateur If there was a breaking change between chrono and time crates, I'd think that using the, using chrono's `Duration` lets me rely on the chrono crate to fix the problem, so I can just update that one dependency without having to make a code change myself.

Comment: As of May/2020, using `chrono::Duration` is actually necessary, since `time::Duration` doesn't implement the addition trait.