# No function or associated item named `now` found for struct `chrono::offset::utc::Utc` in the current scope

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

The method I'm trying to use is documented [here](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html#method.now).

Here is the code I'm trying to use it in:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

struct Attributes {
    time: Option<DateTime<Utc>>,
}


impl Default for Attributes {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Attributes {
            time: Some(chrono::offset::Utc::now()),
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get on running cargo build:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `now` found for struct `chrono::offset::utc::Utc` in the current scope
   --> src/event/v03/attributes.rs:165:45
    |
165 |             time: Some(chrono::offset::Utc::now()),
    |                                             ^^^ function or associated item not found in `chrono::offset::utc::Utc`
```

I'm not sure where the issue is, but I'm sure the method exists. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are doing something wrong, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710935/7076153, check your version, your code compile with last chrono version https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28b01d00688fc26653cb5c639163d7a8

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the error was that I was trying t use the no_std version of the library, and forgot to enable the `clock` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was quite a silly mistake on my end. I overlooked the fact that I was using `chrono` with the `std` feature turned off. This required me disabling all other default features, including the feature `clock` which facilitates `chrono::offset::Utc::now()`.